# 404: Page Not Found, when trying to download file in Laravel 8

Tags: download, http-status-code-404, laravel-8

I am able to Upload files, But When I try to **download PDF, it throws 404: Page Not Found**..I don't know where I am wrong?
**My Controller is :**

```
public function Download(Request $request,$path)
            {
                $path = public_path("dummy.pdf"); 
                $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
                $fileName = time().'.pdf';
                if (file_exists($path)) {
                    return Storage::download($path, $fileName, $headers);
                } else {
                    echo('File not found.');
                }
            }//end of method
```

**Routes Are :**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/login',[AdminController::class,'Index'])->name('admin_login');
    Route::post('/login/owner',[AdminController::class,'Login'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::get('/dashboard',[AdminController::class,'Dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('/Logout',[AdminController::class,'AdminLogout'])->name('admin.logout')->middleware('admin');

    /*--------------- File Upload Route---------*/

    Route::get('/upload-file', [NoteController::class, 'createForm'])->name('upload-file');
    Route::post('/upload-file', [NoteController::class, 'fileUpload'])->name('fileUpload');
    Route::get('/notes', [NoteController::class, 'ViewNote'])->name('myNote');
    Route::get('/download', [NoteController::class, 'Download'])->name('download');
```

**And the View File is..**

```
 <tbody>
                @foreach ($notes as $note)
                    
               
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $note->path }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $note->user_type }}</td>
                    <td> {{ $note->description }}</td>
                    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{ route('download',$note->path) }}">Download</a></td>
                    
                    
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                
            </tbody>
```

Comment: What does the url you're accessing look like? Did you try to `dd($path)` right at the top of your method? Does your route take a parameter?

Comment: @brombeer Updated My Route like... ` Route::get('/download{path}', [NoteController::class, 'Download'])->name('download'); `

Comment: public function Download($path)
            {
                dd($path);  }